# Very Basic Meteor Routing To Template

Tags: templates, meteor, router

Meteor 0.8.0.1 - what I understood from the docs, this minimal app

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor Routing Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> renderPage}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</template>
```

and

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/hi':'hello',
});
```

should fetch and render the template named hello upon `localhost:3000/hi`. Instead, the text *hello* is being rendered into an empty html (i.e. the meteor header is not loaded).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add iron-router (-:

```
mrt add iron-router
```

And try this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('hi', {
    path: '/hi',
    template: 'hello'
  });
});
```

And change to

```
<body>
  {{> yield}}
</body>
```

Comment: This is using the iron router. I know the original router is **deprecated** and using iron router is recommended. However I wanted to use the original router. So does this mean, `router` is incopatible to `meteor 0.8`? Anyway, the way you suggest it does work. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to use original router ... it's awful. Iron-router - very, very cool and powerful.